# Problema callback javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

Este es el problema:

Escribe una función llamada todos en el prototipo de Arrays, que recibe una función (callback). Asumir que fn devuelve siempre true o false.
La función todos debe devolver true si fn devuelve true cuando la invocamos pasándole de a uno todos los elemento del array la función todos debe devolver false, si algún elemento del array hace que fn devuelva false;

Por ejemplo:

[1,2,3].todos(function(elem) {return elem < 10;}); devuelve true

[1,2,3].todos(function(elem) {return elem < 2;}); devuelve false

Este es el código que inténtente:

```
function todos(fn) {
Array.prototype.todos = function (elem) {
    for( var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++ )
      if( elem[i] < 10 ) {
      return true;
      }
      if( elem[i] < 2 ) {
      return false;
      }
    }
}
```

Pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias

Este es el test de verificación

```
const todos = require('../09.js');

describe('todos', function() {
  todos();
  arreglo = [1,2,3]
  it('should return true', function() {
      expect([1,2,3].todos(function(elem) { return elem < 10; })).toBe(true);
  });
  it('should return false', function() {
    expect([1,2,3].todos(function(elem) { return elem < 2; })).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si es esto lo que buscas.

La explicación es más o menos el enunciado de lo que pedias. La solución son solo las 3 primeras líneas, que es añadir al prototype una función que recibe como parámetro una callback. El this.every es otro método del prototype, que devuelve true cuando todos los elementos del array cumplen una condición, que en este caso sería la de la callback. He creado la función test a parte para que se viera más sencillo, pero también se podía poner dicha función entro del parámetro que se envía cuando se invoca el método todos. Lo de test es solo para testear el resultado.

```js
  Array.prototype.todos = function(callback) {
      return this.every(x => callback(x))
  }

  const test = [1,2,3].todos(check);

  function check(num){
      return num < 3;
  }

  console.log(test);
```

Comment: gracias tiene un test lo anexo a la pregunta no se si sirva de alto, si funciona pero no comprendo la solución serias tan amable de explicarme. Gracias

Comment: La explicacion es mas o menos el enunciado de lo que pedias. La solución son solo las 3 primeras lineas, que es añadir al prototype una función que recibe como parámetro una callback. El `this.every` es otro método del prototype, que devuelve true cuando todos los elementos del array cumplen una cóndición, que en este caso sería la de la callback. He creado la función test a parte para que se viera mas sencillo, pero también se podía poner dicha función entro del parámetro que se envía cuando se invoca el método todos. Lo de test es solo para testear el resultado.

Comment: Es por ello que responder sólo con código sin ningún tipo de explicación se considera de baja calidad. Edita tu respuesta y agrega una breve explicación de porqué tu código es válido para solucionar el problema. Tienes suficiente reputación para saber [answer]. Saludos

Comment: Gracias amigo por la respuesta entiendo es otro prototipo every.

Comment: Si bien responde a la pregunta, no es una buena respuesta. Hubiera sido más simple usar la función `every` directamente o si quieres darle un alias: `Array.prototype.todos = Array.prototype.every`

Answer (score 0):

lo realice de la siguiente manera:

```
   Array.prototype.todos = function(callback) {
      this.forEach(item => {
  // Analizar el resultado de la función de retorno o "callback"
      if(callback(item)) {
      // Si devuelve verdadero, agregar elemento
      newArray.push(item);
      }
    });
   return (this.lenght === newArray.lenght);
   };
```